# Augmenting JSON from REST about additional data within AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, underscore.js, lodash

EDIT (SOLUTION): http://plnkr.co/edit/SjzpmQqMPuOCvcdZn5bV?p=preview

I get following data from a REST-API:

```
[
  {
    "a": "foo"
  },
  {
    "a": "bar"
  }
]
```

but need that:

```
 [
  {
    "a": "foo",
    "activated": false
  },
  {
    "a": "bar",
    "activated": true
  }
]
```

how could I do that within angular, how can I principally add some new properties so that I can react on their change may be with a new style.

SECOND QUESTION: Or maybe I need following transformation:

```
{
  "a": {
    "foo": true,
    "bar": false
  }
}
```

Is there an "Angular-way" to do that? Do I have to use libraries like lodash, underscore etc.. ?

Comment: It's not necessarily an angular thing. You'd just process it in vanilla javascript.

Comment: Do you have some context to what you're doing? Inserting values from an input?

Comment: Without knowing the format of where the additional data is coming from it's hard to offer more specific advice, but you can use the .map() function in javscript to do this

something like  `array.map(function(singer) { singer.c = ""; ... return singer;});`

- [MDN article on the map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Are you using angular-resource or $http directly?

Comment: Instead of modifying your question adding a link to a possible answer, it is better (in order to be helpful for future) to create an other post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [underscorejs's extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) method.

http://jsfiddle.net/2676saju/

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
        {{vm.list | json}}
    </div>
    <script>
        angular.module('app', [])
          .controller('MyController', function () {
              var vm = this;
              var list = [{
                  "a": "foo"
              }, {
                  "a": "bar"
              }];

              vm.list = _.each(list, function (item) {
                  var result = _.random(0, 100) % 2 ? true : false;
                  _.extend(item, { activated: result });
              });
          });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result**

```
[ { "a": "foo", "activated": false }, { "a": "bar", "activated": true } ]
```

Comment: I'm afraid but that would be still the solution today.. Thank you for your effords..

Comment: Could you answer the second question too? Thank you!

Comment: 2nd question is nothing but assigning the array. [http://jsfiddle.net/crvo9rbv](http://jsfiddle.net/crvo9rbv).

Answer (score 0):

```
array[1].c = "Michael Jackson";
array[1].d = ["Thriller..."]
```

and `array[0].c` for george michael...

Comment: :) No, that's not the answer, it is about augmenting JSON-Structures principally.. Maybe there is a kind of MATCH-Library?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't get that from the title, maybe Im a bit slow today. You mean  something along the lines of serialization of objects, "hibernate"-style? but for client?

Comment: I want to add some new properties something like "active", so that I can react on its change may be with a new style..

Comment: Would it be possible for you to push all the items in an array in the controller and treat them as objects and modify the properties that way? Then you can add properties to a specific element or on the entire collection

Comment: Yes I could do that, but I'am looking for the Angular-way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

For an "Angular way" solution, you can use the `angular.forEach` function

```
angular.module("myApp")
    .controller("myVm", function($scope) {

var vm = $scope;

vm.items = [
  {
    "a": "foo"
  },
  {
    "a": "bar"
  }
];

vm.activeList = [];

var pushItem = function(value,key) {
    var o = {};
    o[value.a] = false;
    this.push(o);
};

angular.forEach(vm.items, pushItem, vm.activeList);

});
```

**OUTPUT**

```
activeList = [{"foo":false},{"bar":false}]
```

For more information on the `angular.forEach` function, see the [AngularJS angular.forEach API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)